# connecting to database issue in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and while trying to connect to database in localhost using xammp iam getting an error that

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

my connection code is that

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'hindutemples'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

but 'hindutemples' database exists i dnt know why it is trying to connect with homestead

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does your DB use a port to connect? If it does, add `'port' => whatever` at the end of `mysql` array.

Comment: no its not using any port to connect ,even though i tried that its not working

Comment: What's the info in your `.env` file, related to the database anyway?

Comment: no by default its like that only while downloading laravel

Comment: Change the values in `.env` to the ones you currently have in the config file. It should work fine after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename `.env.example` to `.env`. Then set appropriate values in `.env` files. It should work.

**UPDATE**

Laravel 5 stores settings in `.env` file. Laravel 5 comes with default `.env.example` file in a root folder. If you can not find it in project root it may have been hidden.

You need to rename `.env.example` or create new `.env` file inside project root and put app settings in it like given below,

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=0SewSBZ47SfA4vRV6o8BeW74PMFwPpoX

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=hindutemples
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

`env()` returns values from `.env` files. if it could not find setting in `.env` file it returns `false` or if supplied default e.g. `env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead')` it will return default value. in your case it can not find `.env` setting so it is returning `homestead` as a username and hence error.

[Read More](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration)